# How can I get the work week and day number in VB (outlook 2010)?

Tags: vb.net, outlook-2010

We send out a daily email using Outlook that contains the work week and day in the format of WW.D  Our work week starts on Monday, so like today would be 50.2  How can I add this programatically using VB?

```
Sub MakeItem()
    Dim objMail As MailItem   

    Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Update.oft")
    ' Work week number
    WW = 50.2

    ' Setup Subject replacing the <SHIFT>
    newItem.Subject = Replace("<WorkWeek> Shift Passdown ", "<WorkWeek>", WW)
    newItem.Display

    Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim cal As New GregorianCalendar()
Dim week As Integer = cal.GetWeekOfYear(Date.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
Dim day As Integer = cal.GetDayOfWeek(Date.Now)
Dim workDayId As String = String.Format("{0:00}.{1}", week, day)
```

Comment: this doesn't work in the outlook version of VB.  i get an error "Compile error expected end of statement" for all the lines.

Comment: Oh.  Well, you tagged this question as VB.NET and you didn't specify anywhere that your question was related to VBA.  My solution is only applicable to VB.NET.  It will not work in VBA, which is more akin to VB6 and VBScript.  I recommend that you re-ask your question, but this time tag it appropriately as VBA instead of VB.NET.